# Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have a project working with Vue.js for a long time. Recently an error appeared without me doing anything:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2926:1)
    at Module../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js (chunk-vendors.js:5601:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854:30)
    at fn (app.js:151:20)
    at eval (index.js:7:68)
    at Module../src/router/index.js (app.js:1414:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854:30)
    at fn (app.js:151:20)
    at eval (main.js:15:65)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1390:1)
```

this is my main.js code in Vue CLI 4.5.13 vesion :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import store from './store'

import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js'
import 'es6-promise/auto'
import FirebaseApp from './firebase'

import './assets/css/main.scss'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(FirebaseApp)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* Vue.use(VueClipboards) */

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Look for a place where you used 'window.Vue' and replace it with the import Vue from 'vue' statement

Answer (score 1):

> Recently an error appeared without me doing anything:

Maybe you installed Vue@3 instead of Vue@2.6.14?